# How to compute eigenvector centrality with cytoscape.js

Tags: social-networking, cytoscape.js, network-analysis

I can calculate some network centrality metrics such as degree centrality and closeness centrality using cytoscape.js but I didn't see any built-in function to compute [eigenvector centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvector_centrality) (eigencentrality). Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your link, Page Rank should suffice, as it's a type of eigenvector centrality: http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.pageRank